# Integral with Legendre polynomial: $\int_{-1}^{1}x^{n+2k}P_{n}(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, legendre-polynomials

How to compute the following integral?

> $$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{n+2k}P_{n}(x) dx $$

where $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre function, and $n, k = 1,2, \cdots.$

Comment: Do you mean that $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$?

Comment: Yes $P_n$ is, indeed the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. By using [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula),
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!\space2^n}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n,
$$ one may integrate by parts $n$ times obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} x^{n+2k}P_{n}(x) dx&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\space2^n}\frac{(n+2k)!}{(2k+1)!}\int_{-1}^{1} x^{2k}(x^2-1)^n dx
\\\\&=\frac{(n+2k)!}{n!\space2^n\:(2k+1)!}\int_0^{1} u^{k-1/2}(1-u)^n du
\end{align}
$$ that is, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, using the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) we have

> $$
> \int_{-1}^{1} x^{n+2k}P_{n}(x) \:dx=\frac{2^n(n+2k)!\:(n+k)!}{(2n+2k+1)!\:k!}.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sequence $u_n=\int_{-1}^{1} x^{n+2k}P_{n}(x)$. Use integration by parts (not many choices here) and see what you get regarding the sequence $u_n$. Then you can conclude for every value of $n$.